# Doing some css with jquery Datatables on JS array

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I would like to do some css with my jquery Datatable however the only things I found was with html tables. Is it possible to change the look of a datatable when it takes its data from a js array ?

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    destroy: true,
    "scrollY": "200px",
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "paging": false,       
    data: datatable,
    columns: [
        { title: "title1" },
        { title: "title2" }
    ]
});
```

Is there some parameters I could add here ?

Comment: What type of CSS are you trying to implement?

Comment: @mmushtaq Something like changing the color of the cells,the text,or the border (like we can do when we use an html table).

Comment: Why not. You can do it with datatable as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Look at [**`createdRow`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow) and [**`createdCell`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.createdCell). Here is an example to demonstrate how to use those callbacks :

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  createdRow: function(row, data, dataIndex ) {
    $(row).css('color', 'red')
  },
  columnDefs: [{
    targets: 3,
    createdCell: function(td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
      $(td).css('color', 'green')
    }
  }]
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/qsh3zgcc/**

---

Or, as @mmushtaq points out, do what you wanna do in CSS, as you are used to do it :

```css
table.dataTable tbody tr {
  color: red;
}
table.dataTable tbody tr td:nth-child(4) {
  color: green;
}
```

produces the exact same as the above callbacks.

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/prkf1y90/**